# Display multiple plot in %R magic cells

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I have a problem with jupyterlab, I am piping R within a jupyter notebook running via Python kernel, When I used %Rmagic I can't display multiple plot, is there a solution to overcome this problem, for instance with the example below I want to display two time the same graph, but I just get one output

```
%%R -i scaled_features

# Loading R libraries
require("FactoMineR")
require("factoextra")

# PCA
RES <- PCA(scaled_features, graph = FALSE)
fviz_eig(RES, addlabels = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 50))
fviz_eig(RES, addlabels = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 50))
```

Answer (score 1):

`fviz_eig()` is probably returning an object that is generating plot when "printed" in the console. When in an R magic cell, you likely have to print it explicitly.

For example with ggplot2:

[image: Screenshot]